# Remove duplicate images capture from live stream With IP camers

Tags: python, opencv

I am capturing images from the live stream of camera perfectly but the number of images capturing within seconds of one person. So I need only one perfect image of per person...how will get

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.7:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0")
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('E://final_facematch//facematch-master//haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cap.set(3,640) # set Width
cap.set(4,480) # set Height
def getfilename():
    x = datetime.datetime.now()
    filename=x.strftime("%d")+x.strftime("%m")+x.strftime("%Y")+x.strftime("%H")+x.strftime("%M")+x.strftime("%S")+""+str(random.randint(1,300))+".jpg"
    return filename
while True:
    ret, gray = cap.read()
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
         gray,
         scaleFactor=1.3,
         minNeighbors=15,      
         minSize=(65, 65))
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(gray,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_color = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        face_cascade = 
        cv2.imwrite("E:/python_pro/dataset/"+getfilename(),roi_color)
cv2.imshow('video', gray)    
k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
```

Comment: Wait ... What ?

Comment: I have read this question four times now and this doesnt look like a python question. Did you use any python in this process? can you share it with us?

Comment: Can you show the code snippets? Possibly I can think of an answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a prefect image, but you can limit to a single image. By waiting for a few seconds after you capture it, so that the frames' screenshots don't flood your system.

You can put a start_time (initialized after capturing the frame or using imwrite) and an end_time (keep changing in the loop) and check

```
if end_time - start_time > 30
```

i.e wait for 30 seconds before resuming to your detection, whatever is it you're trying to achieve.

if you can put your code in here I might be able to help better.

Edit to the above answer after seeing the code:

```
start_time = 10
while True:
    end_time = time.time()
    ret, gray = cap.read()
    if end_time - start_time > 30:
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=15, minSize=(65, 65))
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(gray, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            roi_color = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            face_cascade = cv2.imwrite("E:/python_pro/dataset/" + getfilename(), roi_color)
            start_time = time.time()

    cv2.imshow('video', gray)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
```

This code will wait for 30 seconds after the program clicks a picture when it detects a face.

Comment: your code fine for one person but I want an image of a group of person and per person one or two image.

Comment: you can condition the time to a particular person. I changed start_time when anyone is recognized. You can change it when a specific person is spotted and not click their picture for next 30 seconds.